# Terrain Ruggedness Index Returning Warning (ArcHydro)

Tags: python, arcgis

[Screenshot of the warning I am receiving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5P0B.jpg)

I am attempting to use the Terrain Ruggedness Index (TRI) in Arcgis Pro, which is part of the ArcHydro toolbox and it keeps returning a warning and I'm not sure what is wrong. I've used the elevation DEM that I am inputting for the TRI already for slope and aspect so the issue isn't the input I don't think.

I've tried looking at the code, but I am not versed in python and could not find any issues, I'm really not sure what to do otherwise.

Comment: Is the output itself wrong in any way, as far as you can tell?